# What is making my cursor 'randomly' disappear when using gnome-teminal?

Tags: gnome, terminal-emulator

It happens often that my cursor on `gnome-terminal` disappears, forcing me to work on a new tab/window. It seems like a random occurrence. Does anyone else experience this? What about other X terminal emulators? How can I fix this (or maybe it's just a bug)?

**update**: A simple work-around is to switch away from the terminal and switch back.

**update 2**: I don't experience this any more, maybe because I'm using GNOME 3 version of the terminal.

Answer (score 106):

If running <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (as described in another answer) doesn't work, it's possible that your TTY has been mangled by some other program you've run.  Try running the `reset` command and then the `clear` command (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, its [equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434240/ctrll-in-terminal)) to initialize your terminal.

Comment: Sometimes after I run this one program (k9s, awesome kubectl terminal UI), this happens. The `reset` command worked, thanks!

Comment: I really should have looked for this answer 10 years ago

Answer (score 103):

You may have inadvertently hit the [VT220 escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) to hide the cursor.  If so, then neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, nor `reset`, nor `clear`, nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will help.

What worked for me was to send the VT220 "unhide" command sequence.

As suggested in a comment from Thomas Dickey, and [the answer from Quigi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/714122/36043) the right way to unhide the cursor is to use the `tput` command to send the command sequence like this:

```
tput cnorm
```

(in my original answer I had been sending the command sequence by invoking `echo -en "\e[?25h"`)

You can learn more about `cnorm` and all the other possible command sequences you can send with `tput` by looking at the `man 5 terminfo` man page.

Comment: I just hit this, thanks for the answer. I wonder how it happened in the first place, but oh well (:

Comment: This is by far the most likely(and useful) explanation.   Switch off software flow control in the other instances, so ctrl-q/ctrl-s do nothing.

Comment: I guess this escape sequence may show up when we are copying/pasting text from one terminal emulator window to another.

Comment: This happens for me whenever an ssh session gets disconnected. Using `st`, only the `echo -en "\e[?25h"` solution works.

Comment: It's **[VT220](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-2-5.1EC4)**, and the proper way to reset is `tput cnorm`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Interesting! I read the man page for tput but don't see this. Where can I find more info about `cnorm`?

Comment: I hadn't seen Thomas Dickey's comment before.  I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Could it be that you inadvertently press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, sending XOFF to your terminal and thus locking it?

Next time it happens, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to unlock it.

Comment: No, that's not it.

Comment: Aha, that's what [happened](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12107/4319) to me! Thanks to you that I'm learning about Ctrl-Q now!

Comment: Reading extra comments: I always wondered why did my terminal randomly lock. This might be it : D

Answer (score 6):

Try `tput cnorm`.  It brought back the cursor on my xterm.  As it is based on terminal capabilities, it should be general, not specific to a particular terminal.  Also, it's less disruptive than `reset`, and **much** simpler than re-installing software.

Answer (score 1):

Press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) then (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to initialise the terminal.
This worked for me, first selecting the group then initialising.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here when searching for "chromeos terminal cursor disappeared". Turns out that it was just too dark to see in the default "dark theme". Switched to "light theme" instead.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred on my PC with Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME terminal 3.28.2).  I tried the command `reset`, `clear` as well as `Ctrl+L` and these did not enable the cursor for me.

I gave in and used the mouse with the menu item 'Terminal|Reset and Clear' and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous inspection, try and errors, I can say that the input method (especially non-latin-letter language) may encounter this problem. I use HIME-IM and I believe sometimes it "kidnaps" the input cursor. Changing terminal software/apps does not help if being kidnapped. However, here are some solutions if none of the above works:

1. Just do an input method **switch** (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>), and then the cursor comes back in the terminals,

or

2. Open up the input method for configuration and then close it without anything else, and then it comes back.

This is really annoying but the disappearance of the cursor is more annoying. FYI

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64-bit with Gnome 42.9 and Wayland, the cursor disappeared in all terminal apps for me, but worked fine in other applications like Firefox. I'm not sure what I did to cause it (I switch between applications with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, so that may have been involved).

None of the other escape sequences or keyboard commands in this thread restored the cursor in my case. However, I was able to fix the issue by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while keeping <kbd>Alt</kbd> held, then wiggling the cursor on the application selection menu.

Answer (score -1):

reinstalling gnome,gnome-terminal, and gnome-core solved it for me.