# How to Navigate within bash's Reverse Search?

Tags: bash, command-history, search

Bash offers the functionality to reverse search via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Then one can type in a part of a command it will show a fitting entry from the history.

Assume this is my history:

```
vim foo1
vim foo2 # I want to go here
vim foo3 # this is where I land, how to go back?
```

I search for `foo`. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> again shows the next fitting search entry. Often it happens to me, that I am too fast and navigate past my intended result and `vim foo3` is shown and now I want to go back to `vim foo2`.

Hence my question is: How do I navigate within the reverse search?

Comment: Which terminal you use? Eg. gnome-terminal, konsole, so on...

Comment: Well I am not too familiar with it... The key should be ctrl+S, but [some terminals](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/48880) seem to eat the key, before it reaches the reverse-search

Comment: Ctrl+shift+R - forward search while ctrl + R

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/how-to-cycle-through-reverse-i-search-in-bash

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r/791800#791800

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can access this via the `forward-search-history` function which is bind per default to <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd>. Unfortunately <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> is used to signal `xoff` per default which means you can't use it to change the direction of the search. There are two solutions for solving the problem, one disabling sending the `xoff/xon` signaling and the other change the keybinding for `forward-search-history`

## Disable xon/xoff

Run `stty -ixon` in your terminal or add it to your `~/.bashrc`. This allows you to use <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> to use the `forward-search-history` history function.

For more information about control flow have a look at [How to unfreeze after accidentally pressing Ctrl-S in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal) and some of the answers

## Change the keybinding

If you don't want to change the default behavior of <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> you can change the keybinding for `forward-search-history` with `bind`. As most keys are already defined in bash you may have to get creative:

```
bind "\C-t":forward-search-history
```

This will bind <kbd>ctrl+t</kbd> to forward-search-history, but please be aware that per default <kbd>ctrl+t</kbd> runs `transpose-chars`

Comment: I tried your first solution `stty -ixon` in `zsh` and it works very well. However are there any possibly unwanted side effects in disabling the `xoff/xon` signaling?

Comment: @student You can't use `ctrl+s` for pausing the terminal output any longer. If you never used it before this is no problem

Comment: For what it's worth, I went with the second solution. Great stuff ! I never knew you could freeze the console by pressing `C-s`.. very useful when using tail on server logs. Neat ! (I wish I had another upvote :) )

Comment: I couldn't get option #2 to work on OSX. I had to do this instead: `bind '"\C-t": history-search-forward'`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the basic reverse search and forward search provided by your bash, you may want to look into:

[**fzf**](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), a self-described "command-line fuzzy finder".

It can replace the default reverse search of your bash (and other terminals).

Its benefits are that it:

- prints a list of your commands from history

  - toggles chronological or relevance sorting by hitting Ctrl + R again
- can be navigated via arrow keys (or Ctrl + J / Ctrl + K)
- allows searching for multiple needles

My workflow now completly relies on fzf over the basic reverse search on machines I have control over.