# How to cycle through reverse-i-search in BASH?

Tags: bash

In the terminal, I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to search for a matching command previously typed in BASH. E.g., if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> then `grep`, it lists my last `grep` command, and I can hit enter to use it. This only gives one suggestion though. Is there any way to cycle through other previously typed matching commands?

Answer (score 1086, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you should be able to cycle through
alternatives by repeatedly hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

E.g.:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- `grep`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
  ...

That searches backwards through your history.  To search forward instead, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, but you may need to have set: `stty -ixon` (either by `.bash_profile` or manually) prior to that to disable the XON/XOFF feature which takes over <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. If it happens anyway, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to re-enable screen output (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/162094).)

Comment: +1 -- FYI -- you can also search forward as per [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/791800/568884).

Comment: And use Ctrl+Shift+r for reverse scrolling if you happen to pass over.

Comment: @wiswit `CTRL+SHIFT+r` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @MaximSuslov See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r/791800#791800 You can add `[[ $- == *i* ]] && stty -ixon` to your .bashrc and then `CTRL+s` will work as the reverse of `CTRL+r`

Comment: @JordanArseno I took "search forward" to mean "search for commands I have not yet typed"

Comment: I just tried `STRL+s` and it froze my terminal. Worth mentioning that you can unfreeze it with `CTRL+q` as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12108/265674

Comment: Why did I not take the 30 seconds to look this up until now? I've been grepping my command history for years. Thank you so much.

Comment: #ThingsThatIShouldProbablyHaveLookedUp20YearsAgo

Comment: `stty -ixon` was the missing piece I've needed for 25 years to search forward. Can't believe it annoyed me for so long before I Googled it! :D

Comment: btw: you _have_ to type the `ctrl-R` _first_! if you type `grep ctrl-R` then it only shows the most recent command, and repeated presses of `ctrl-R` do nothing. there's probably a really good reason for this, but i consider it a bug.

Answer (score 354):

If you feel the command will be used frequently, you could add a tag

```
command #useful
```

Then

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> `#useful`

This works because `#` is a comment delimiter, i.e. everything that comes after the symbol is not interpreted as a command. However, it will be recorded in the history and is thus searchable.

Comment: Usually I do like this kind of tagging. #trg_bld #open_log

Comment: where to add this tag?

Comment: @SudipBhandari just after your command. # starts a comment. 
E.g. ls -lah #useful

Comment: Unix had hashtags before it was cool :)))

Comment: That's more a hack, and `.bash_history` gets flushed after a while. You'd be more comfortable using [bash aliases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Comment: Oh man. I was doing this by echoing whatever I wanted to remember, so I could search for the echo. This is better.

Comment: # good # better $ history fzf --query "''good"

Comment: The history file won't get flushed if you increase its line limit to int_max. I personally don't have any desire to truncate my shell history, it's never going to get big enough to be a problem.

Answer (score 75):

You can also set up the up and down arrows to do a slightly different search by adding these lines to ~/.inputrc:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Instead of searching for a substring anywhere in the command (like [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73499/3645)) it will search for a command *starting with the text to the left of the cursor*. For example, if I run these commands:

```
$ ls bart
$ ls fools
```

then type `ls` and press <kbd>Up</kbd> twice, it will show `ls bart` and the cursor in the same place. Compare with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>, where it would find the `ls` twice in the last line, so you'd have to press it once again to find the previous line.

These approaches both have their strengths, and both of them can save a lot of time.

Comment: This is also standard on OS X, so you don't need to create `~/.inputrc` and add those two lines.

Comment: As falconepi have written in the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15430856/813946), on Ubuntu you just need to uncomment in `~/.inputrc` the two lines including history-search-*

Comment: You could also look at this post for more details on this answer: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/the-most-important-command-line-tip-incremental-history-searching-with-inputrc/

Comment: This wasn't standard on my macOS (10.13). I've always missed this functionality!

Comment: a good thing about this is that you can still use ctrl-p/ctrl-n for regular skimming through history

Answer (score 29):

There's a replacement for built-in <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> called [hstr](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr). It allows to search command history matching all search tokens at the same time (among other things), and cycle through result using arrow keys:

[image: Example]

Here's is a [demo screencast](https://gistcdn.githack.com/saaj/70f5710fcc8943f6f84f4226ad275b28/raw/0e320c714a63630c1d512511dbf13ce5e7c44101/73498.svg).

It can be installed on a Debian-family OS like:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ultradvorka/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install hstr

hstr --show-configuration >> ~/.bashrc
```

And then use <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> (after reopening the terminal).

Comment: This MUST be the accepted answer in my view. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome, working!!!

Comment: Newer and a bit fancier: https://github.com/ellie/atuin