# Scripts stalling in `screen` session

Tags: gnu-screen

Every couple of months I return to a `gnu screen` session just to find out that the running script was stalling for hours or days. My suspicion is, that I, while I try to detach, accidentally press some key combination that makes the process halt. When I attach later and notice the stalling I often see that my tries to detach have left command line input like `D^[[D^[[D` or `^[[`. But I was not able reproduce it. Do you have an idea?

I experienced this behaviour with python scripts and C++ code.

Comment: ^[[D is the character string typically created by pressing the "left cursor" key.    Pauses are likely to happen if you press control-S by mistake when aiming for control-A.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Here a link I found searching for control-s http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal @stehpen, can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^[[D` is a key sequence normally created by pressing the *cursor left* key.  This indicates you hit this key by mistake before detaching the session.

Screen pauses may be caused by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keys.  This is using Xon/Xoff flow control.  It can be restarted with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.   Since the `S` key is next to the `A` key it's possible you hit this by mistake when detaching the session.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen answered, it's likely that the script is stopped because you've hit XOFF or `^S` by accident.

Apart from not hitting it, you can disable software flow control by running `stty -ixon` in that terminal. (I seem to have that in my `.bash_profile`, I think it's because I've stopped my IRC client too often with it.)