# How to permanently disable Ctrl-s in terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal) I understand that to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> the `stty -ixon` command can be used and it works, but as soon as I close the terminal and open another I have to re-enter the command.

To permanently disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I have made a `startup.sh` that contains the `stty -ixon` command and run it with `crontab` at `@reboot` but it does not work.

So what will be the solution to permanently disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>?

Comment: Reminder: if you hit `CTRL+S` by mistake, you can use `CTRL+Q` to restore data flow from the terminal.

Comment: The reason your `startup.sh` does not work, but the accepted answer does work, is that it has to be done every time a new (pseudo)terminal is activated.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> permanently in terminal just add this line at the end of your `.bashrc` script (generally in your home directory)

```
stty -ixon
```

An explanation of why this exists and what it relates to can be found in this answer: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/7266

Comment: a small explanation of what it does would be nice

Comment: My `.bashrc` complains about that when I log into my window manager - a modal dialog with an error is displayed (only on Desktop with graphical wm, server ok).

Answer (score 19):

As others have mentioned, the required fix is adding `stty -ixon` to your `~/.bashrc` file. However, it should be protected from execution by non-interactive shells:

```
if [[ -t 0 && $- = *i* ]]
then
    stty -ixon
fi
```

This should avoid errors when there is no TTY or interactive session in the first place, so "internal" shell invocations of desktop environments etc. will not cause error messages.

Comment: In the beginning of Ubuntu 20.04's default `~/.bashrc` such protection is already there:
```# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: In another systems there can be equivalent in `~/.bashrc`:
`# If not running interactively, don't do anything`
`[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`