# How to disable Ctrl+S in terminal applications started from file manager or via shortcut?

Tags: terminal, vim, stty

I've successfully disabled `Ctrl`+`S` in terminal using instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332793/492495).
However, if I launch a ***terminal*** programs (namely terminal vim) from "outside the terminal", `Ctrl`+`S` still freezes the screen.

What I mean by "outside the terminal":

- Using a keyboard shortcut to run something like `kitty -e vim` to open vim in terminal
- Using [vimserver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588202/how-to-open-new-files-in-a-same-vim-instance-from-my-file-manager-or-from-comman/588203#588203) to launch terminal vim from the file manager, which in the end pretty much does the same as above

Is there a way around this? (Other than unlearning the habit of constantly saving with `Ctrl`+`S` ;)

(There are reasons I cannot and don't want to use gVim.
Running `stty -ixon` from inside vim doesn't work, and I'm sure there are good reasons why not – I'm not really familiar with stty yet...)

Comment: You can also try undefining the stop character: `stty stop undef`. I don't know if this will persist in more situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
silent !stty -ixon
```

If that creates problems with a non-tty `vim` like `gvim` (no idea, not able to test it), try this:

```
silent !test -t 0 && stty -ixon
```

---

[It looks like](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5775#issuecomment-636461202) they decided to make `-ixon` the default in recent versions of vim, so this is soon going to stop being an issue with vim (notice that the original patch from the originator of the [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5775) was untested garbage, but the final [patch](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/928eec649b8af389de0fdb7aba2034d27df3e058) got it right).

Generally (with other programs), there's no general solution ;-)

xterm has a `ttyModes` resource (and `-tm` option) which can be used to set the initial modes, but which does **not** support `-ixon`. I don't think that `kitty` has even that.

---

> Running `stty -ixon` from inside vim doesn't work

That's because `vim` restores the initial (usually non-raw) state of the terminal before running external commands via `:!command`, and then changes it back to raw mode upon replying to the "Press ENTER or type command" prompt, so any changes performed by `command` are lost.

---

As an extra note, the common folklore spread on this site & elsewhere (that `^S`/`^Q` are just an anachronistic carryover from the time before `less` and `tmux`, etc) is wrong; software flow control is something you **must** use on any serial line *without* RTS/CTS out-of-band signaling (*especially* on a line with high baud rate), and something that is totally useless on any kind of virtual tty.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/655592/432679) for the kind of problems that just blindly turning `IXON` off (in that case by the ssh client on the local tty) may cause for people using actual serial lines to connect to their devices. Most programs which call `cfmakeraw` (or duplicate it exactly) are bound to fail in the same way (`script(1)` is the first one that comes to mind).

Comment: @Quasímodo Thanks, almost forgot!
The `silent !resize > /dev/null` is to fix glitches you mention [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26802/38133)? I haven't encountered them but I guess it doesn't hurt being preemtive.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. Also apparently `resize` is an `xterm` thing