# What to use when the "ls" command doesn't work?

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

I tried to use the `ls` command and got an error:

```
bash: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

What can I use instead of this command?

Comment: Perhaps you screwed up your `libc*so` or your `ld-linux*so`

Comment: If you have previously installed it, or if you are able to install it, consider having `sash`; it is a static shell with many builtins, including commands like `ls`, `cp`, `tar` etc....

Comment: Personally, I would focus on fixing my system, unless this is some wacky thought experiment.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch never heard of it, but Busybox is commonly available and can step in.

Comment: ...a system rescue cd?

Comment: A question _addressing the actual problem_ in such cases is http://superuser.com/questions/435988/ .  And far from being uncommon, as implied, [`sash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) is available [on Ubuntu Linux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sash.1.html), as [shells/sash](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/shells.html#sash-3.8) in the FreeBSD ports tree, as [a Gentoo package](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/app-shells/sash), as well as other places including [directly from its author](http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `echo` or `find` commands instead of `ls`:

```
echo *
```

or:

```
find -printf "%M\t%u\t%g\t%p\n"
```

Comment: I would use `echo -- *`

Comment: what's the difference? It will give you the same output

Comment: @Invoker: If you happen to have a file called `-n` in the current directory, that would get interpreted as a flag, not something to echo.

Comment: I don't think you can create file `-n` `[admin ~]$ touch -n
touch: invalid option -- 'n'
Try `touch --help' for more information.``

Comment: It would be `touch ./-n`

Comment: ok I did and used my coomand `echo *`         
`[admin ~]$ touch ./-n
[admin ~]$ ls
Desktop    Downloads  -n        Public     test
Documents  Music      Pictures  Templates  Videos
[admin5 ~]$ echo *
Desktop Documents Downloads Music -n Pictures Public Templates test Videos`
and  I can see my file `-n`

Comment: so what's the difference ?

Comment: @Invoker Alphabetical order matters. Run that oneliner for a case where that makes a difference: `rm -rf /tmp/foo && mkdir /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo && touch ./-n oops && set -x && ls && echo *`

Comment: `echo` seems not to honor `--`, *per se*.  So how is `echo -- *` any better than `echo "" *` or, better yet, `echo "The file(s) are:" *`?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: echo takes a single dash for that purpose, not two dashes: `echo - *`.

Comment: @Zorawar why? other commands like `rm` we use `--` two dashes

Comment: you should update your command bfr more users use that 'inaccurate' command, sorry i dont mean to be rude but pls dont give 'inaccurate' commands

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: god knows. It should be two dashes as with most other (GNU) commands so that people aren't caught out. Probably for historical reasons and backwards compatibility if I had to guess...

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: but, I should add, it may not be respected by all versions of echo, whether builtin or external command...

Comment: @G-Man - well, in the first place, it's apparent that the execution environment is at least a little strange, and that compilation defaults cannot be assumed. And if the version of `bash` being run has been compiled with [*`--enable-xpg-echo-default`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Optional-Features.html):
...`echo` ... expand[s] backslash-escaped characters by default ... more like the ... [`echo` specified in] Single Unix Specification, version 3...* then, well, `echo`'s output is not necessarily a reliable representation of the filenames in question.

Comment: @ EdwardTorvalds: not `echo -- *`, prefer the good habit of using: `echo ./*` (some systems will not have the -- option to echo. And even linux probably have programs that don't have '--' as well, so the good habit of using ./ instead works in all those cases and is better.)

Comment: Another workaround: ``a=(*);echo -n "${a[*]}"$'\n'``.

Answer (score 25):

You can also use the `printf` command, instead of echo:

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

`printf` is superior to `echo` in this situation in that `echo` does **not** respect the "double dash" (`--`) to signify the end of the argument list (on some systems, including Ubuntu 14.04 which is what I tested it on):

```
llama@llama:~$ mkdir -p Misc/unix210948
llama@llama:~$ cd !$
cd Misc/unix210948
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ touch -- -n
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ ls
-n
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ echo *
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ echo -- *
-- -n
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ printf '%s\n' *
-n
```

In this case, you cannot achieve the desired result with `echo` (since a file called `-n` gets interpreted as an option, and the double dash doesn't work, so you must use `printf`).

Note that you should **always** use a format string like the above when dealing with unknown data with `printf`, since otherwise you could receive unexpected results (thanks to @G-Man for pointing this out in the comments!):

```
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ rm ./-n
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ touch '\n'
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ ls
\n
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ printf -- *

llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ printf '%s\n' *
\n
```

A file called `\n` is interpreted as a newline by `printf`. To avoid this, we use a formatting string for `printf` (`%s`) and pass it the names of the files (expanded via globbing, as before).

This `printf` + formatting string solution can handle a wide variety of filenames (and also treats "hidden" files, that is, those starting with a `.`, the same as `ls`):

```
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ rm ./*
zsh: sure you want to delete all the files in /home/llama/Misc/unix210948/. [yn]? y
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ touch -- '-n' '\n' 'name with spaces' '.hidden'
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ ls
-n  \n  name with spaces
llama@llama:~/Misc/unix210948$ printf '%s\n' *
-n
\n
name with spaces
```

If your `printf` supports `%q`, you could also use that (`printf '%q\n' *`). This will escape spaces, newlines, etc. if there are any strange characters in your filenames. (Thanks to [@muru in chat for pointing this out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22304450#22304450)!)

Comment: When dealing with unknown data, you should ***ALWAYS*** use `'%s'` (with `\n` and/or any other constant text you want).  For example, try the commands `touch '%.0s' foo bar; ls; printf -- *`.  Conversely, I don't see why you need `--` when you have a `'%s\n'` format string.

Comment: @G-Man Good point! Thanks, I overlooked the unnecessary `--` with the format string, and I've edited my post to address the other thing.

Comment: The `-n` filename honestly *shouldn't* be a problem at all for a POSIX-2001+ `echo` - on SUSv3 systems the `echo` utility is *required* not to accept any options whatsoever. `bash`'s `echo` and some others do handle the option though, but `bash` can be compiled with the build option `--enable-xpg-echo-default` to make it behave correctly all of the time. *Correct* behavior for `echo`, though, means *always* interpreting backlash escapes in its arguments. So any filename with a C-style escape *would not* be written to output w/ fidelity - `echo` would translate it.

Comment: please, please, everyone should stop recommanding '--' when the unix faq since more than 10 years explain that using "./" is better and more portable (works with all programs even the (many) ones that dont handle '--' )

Comment: @OliverDulac - not even that would hel[ w/ a conformant `echo`.

Answer (score 8):

You should probably use the `file` and `uname` utilities to get a better idea of just what the hell is going on with your machine. Your error is indicative of a binary executable compiled for a system architecture incompatible with that on which it is invoked.

On my machine:

```sh
uname -m; file /bin/ls
```

...prints...

```sh
x86_64
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=..., stripped
```

...because all is right with the world there. However, here's a little run of some commands run from my android tablet on an `ssh` connection to my desktop...

```sh
#first copy android ls to desktop
scp /system/bin/ls "$ssh:arm_ls"
```

---

```sh
ls               100%  151KB 151.4KB/s   00:00
```

---

```sh
#next login to desktop and run the following
ssh "$ssh" '
   HOME=./arm_ls
   chmod +x ~
   file ~
   bash -c ~ ||
   rm ~
'
```

---

```sh
./arm_ls: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker, stripped
bash: ./arm_ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: This is a great answer that covers one scenario and addresses the potential underlying cause.

Comment: misread ^^ sorry. why not just copy and use file? why the whole homedir thing? scp to desktop, file on it, and bash ./it ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac -hmm.. i'mnn not sure i get gist of what youre asking exactly. The `HOME=` thing is so i can just do `~` a bunch of times instead of `./arm_ls`  - for convenience. The whole point of the exercice is that i cannot use the arm binary on my x86 desktop, and i wanted the output of `file` to show that it is a very differnt kind of binary than the sydtem's native one - which is shown at top. And so rather than shpw a whole cross-compile, i chose to cpy an incompatible binary i had available to me on my arm dev to my x86 device and show the results and how to ger the `bash` error.

Comment: oh, it was just to save a few typing? ok, but I think it makes it more confusing than it should be (it's not codegolf ^^)

Comment: @OliverDulac - of course it's not code gold, but it's convenient, it's not at all ambiguous, and i hate thumb typing.

Answer (score 5):

Using bash (or many other shells), you can use tab completion to list files:

```
$ thisisnotacommand ./public_html/<TAB>
acc/              papers/           android/          l/
sdr/              blast             formalcss.html    switch/
busy/             formalcss.tar.gz  others/           together.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want something more like `ls -l` (file size, permissions, owner, timestamps, etc), then `stat -- *` might be helpful:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   4 Jun 20 21:50 a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 279 Jun 20 21:50 b.txt
$ stat -- *
  File: ‘a.txt’
  Size: 4           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 787691      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2015-06-20 21:50:23.395223851 -0700
Modify: 2015-06-20 21:50:23.395223851 -0700
Change: 2015-06-20 21:50:23.395223851 -0700
 Birth: -
  File: ‘b.txt’
  Size: 279         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 844130      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)
Access: 2015-06-20 21:50:31.763084155 -0700
Modify: 2015-06-20 21:50:51.066758216 -0700
Change: 2015-06-20 21:50:51.066758216 -0700
 Birth: -
$
```

---

Alternatively if all you wanted to do is misspell `ls`, then [try `sl` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304/34061). ;-) (go on - try it... you might have to install it)

Answer (score 3):

There is very similar utility available on many systems:

```
dir
```

According to the info pages it is equivalent to `ls -C -b`, but it is standalone binary file.

The benefit of using `dir` (instead of for example shell completion system) is availability of different options like sorting, showing hidden files, colouring etc., just like in the standard `ls` program.

BTW, I guess its name comes from windows (or rather dos) system.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 echo -- *
    find . -printf "%M\t%u\t%g\t%p\n"
    ls -C -b
```